SymFromAddr is unusable with MinGW toolchain?
I am trying to dump symbolized stacktrace when my program crash. I catch the crash event with SetUnhandledExceptionFilter. Then I obtain stacktrace with StackWalk. Finally, I obtain symbols from addresses with SymFromAddr. Please see the code below.
// clang-format off
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>
// clang-format on
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

WINAPI LONG ExceptFilter(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS info) {
  const auto retVal = EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
  auto process = GetCurrentProcess();
  auto thread = GetCurrentThread();
  // if (auto ret = SymSetOptions(SYM_LOAD))
  if (auto ret = SymInitialize(process, nullptr, TRUE); ret != TRUE) {
    std::cerr << "SymInitialize failed: " << GetLastError();
    return retVal;
  }
  STACKFRAME64 frame{};
  frame.AddrPC.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
  frame.AddrPC.Offset = info->ContextRecord->Rip;
  frame.AddrFrame.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
  frame.AddrFrame.Offset = info->ContextRecord->Rsp;
  frame.AddrStack.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
  frame.AddrStack.Offset = info->ContextRecord->Rsp;

  char buffer[sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + 1024] = {};
  auto symbolInfo = reinterpret_cast<PSYMBOL_INFO>(&buffer);
  symbolInfo->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
  symbolInfo->MaxNameLen = 1024;
  int index = 0;
  while (StackWalk64(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64, process, thread, &frame,
                     info->ContextRecord, nullptr, &SymFunctionTableAccess64,
                     &SymGetModuleBase64, nullptr) == TRUE) {
    auto pc = frame.AddrPC.Offset;
    // qDebug() << pc;
    std::string symbolName{"(unknown)"};
    if (auto ret = SymFromAddr(process, pc, NULL, symbolInfo); ret == TRUE) {
      symbolName = symbolInfo->Name;
      // qDebug() << index << " " << symbolInfo->Name << " " << pc;
    } else {
      // qDebug() << index << " (unknown) " << pc;
      // std::cerr << "error code: " << GetLastError();
    }
    // const auto msg = QString("%1 - 0x%2 - %3")
    //                      .arg(QString::number(index, 10), 2, u'0')
    //                      .arg(QString::number(pc, 16))
    //                      .arg(symbolName);
    // qDebug() << msg;
    fprintf(stderr, "%02d - %x - %s\n", index, pc, symbolName.c_str());
    ++index;
  }
  SymCleanup(process);
  // qDebug() << "crash!!";
  return retVal;
}


namespace MyNamespace {
__attribute__((noinline)) void Func1() {
  int *ptr = 0;
  *ptr = 1;
}

__attribute__((noinline)) void Func2() { Func1(); }

__attribute__((noinline)) void Func3() { Func2(); }

} // namespace MyNamespace

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(&ExceptFilter);
  
  MyNamespace::Func3();
  return 0;
}

The above minimal code when compiled by mingw g++ compiler and run, yields the above output:
00 - 4018d8 - (unknown)
01 - 4018f2 - (unknown)
02 - 401906 - (unknown)
03 - 401936 - (unknown)
04 - 4013c7 - (unknown)
05 - 4014fb - (unknown)
06 - f010257d - BaseThreadInitThunk
07 - f1e6af28 - RtlUserThreadStart

None of my functions get their symbols displayed. Is it a problem with MinGW or my code?
Edit: Here is the output of my code given the MSVC compiler.
// clang-format off
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>
// clang-format on
// https://blog.csdn.net/qq_33335872/article/details/115206003
// QMainWindow *g_mainWindow;
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

LONG ExceptFilter(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS info) {
  const auto retVal = EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
  auto process = GetCurrentProcess();
  auto thread = GetCurrentThread();
  // if (auto ret = SymSetOptions(SYM_LOAD))
  if (auto ret = SymInitialize(process, nullptr, TRUE); ret != TRUE) {
    std::cerr << "SymInitialize failed: " << GetLastError();
    return retVal;
  }
  STACKFRAME64 frame{};
  frame.AddrPC.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
  frame.AddrPC.Offset = info->ContextRecord->Rip;
  frame.AddrFrame.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
  frame.AddrFrame.Offset = info->ContextRecord->Rsp;
  frame.AddrStack.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
  frame.AddrStack.Offset = info->ContextRecord->Rsp;

  char buffer[sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + 1024] = {};
  auto symbolInfo = reinterpret_cast<PSYMBOL_INFO>(&buffer);
  symbolInfo->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
  symbolInfo->MaxNameLen = 1024;
  int index = 0;
  while (StackWalk64(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64, process, thread, &frame,
                     info->ContextRecord, nullptr, &SymFunctionTableAccess64,
                     &SymGetModuleBase64, nullptr) == TRUE) {
    auto pc = frame.AddrPC.Offset;
    // qDebug() << pc;
    std::string symbolName{"(unknown)"};
    if (auto ret = SymFromAddr(process, pc, NULL, symbolInfo); ret == TRUE) {
      symbolName = symbolInfo->Name;
      // qDebug() << index << " " << symbolInfo->Name << " " << pc;
    } else {
      // qDebug() << index << " (unknown) " << pc;
      // std::cerr << "error code: " << GetLastError();
    }
    // const auto msg = QString("%1 - 0x%2 - %3")
    //                      .arg(QString::number(index, 10), 2, u'0')
    //                      .arg(QString::number(pc, 16))
    //                      .arg(symbolName);
    // qDebug() << msg;
    fprintf(stderr, "%02d - %llx - %s\n", index, pc, symbolName.c_str());
    ++index;
  }
  SymCleanup(process);
  // qDebug() << "crash!!";
  return retVal;
}


namespace MyNamespace {
void Func1() {
  int *ptr = 0;
  *ptr = 1;
}

void Func2() { Func1(); }

void Func3() { Func2(); }

} // namespace MyNamespace

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(&ExceptFilter);
  
  MyNamespace::Func3();
  return 0;
}


Just use x64 toolchain:
00 - 7ff6820b1ce2 - MyNamespace::Func1
01 - 7ff6820b1d0b - MyNamespace::Func2
02 - 7ff6820b1d2b - MyNamespace::Func3
03 - 7ff6820b1d60 - main
04 - 7ff6820b5be9 - invoke_main
05 - 7ff6820b5a92 - __scrt_common_main_seh
06 - 7ff6820b594e - __scrt_common_main
07 - 7ff6820b5c7e - mainCRTStartup
08 - 7ffcf010257d - BaseThreadInitThunk
09 - 7ffcf1e6af28 - RtlUserThreadStart

With MSVC, my code works just fine.
Plus: If you ever knew the StackWalker project on Github, you will see that this project explicitly bans its usage with GCC.
So, I guess the problem lies in the compilers, right?
Edit: So, my question is: how can I get sensible symbols of my code (not kernel's code) using MinGW g++? Many thanks!

"I am trying to dump symbolized stacktrace when my program crash." - Why don't you let WER generate a crash dump instead? In contrast to a stack trace a minidump is actually useful for debugging purposes. If you need to customize minidump generation you can do that as well (see the documentation for MiniDumpWriteDump). A stack trace really only looks useful to folks that think GDB was a debugger.

Thanks for your reply. But, a stacktrace dump is all I need. I've tried the minidump solution before. To analyze a dump file, you have to install WinDbg and possibly Visual Studio to help generate .pdb files. But with a simple stacktrace dump, the problem can be pinned down in most of our usecases.

You won't get a symbolic stack trace without a .pdb, so a .pdb you need either way. The .pdb is generated by the compiler. MSVC has the correct default to dump debug info into an external artifact, whereas other compilers (Clang, GCC) default to compiling debug info into the executable, so generating debug info is generally turned off with the latter. You don't need WinDbg to analyze a minidump. Any Windows debugger will do.

I think it is true. I tried glog again and its symbolize module is NOT enabled under MinGW compiler. By the way, I can still get Qt's symbols. Isn't Qt compiled by MinGW? How is it possible?

You also got symbols for the OS calls. You do because Microsoft provides a public symbol server where the API can download .pdb's from. Qt either has a public symbol server as well or ships the debug symbols (.pdb's) as part of the installation. All of this is enabled by the decision to compile debug information into separate artifacts. I don't know why GNU gets these decisions consistently wrong or why folks love those tools even when interior on pretty much every metric.

Thanks for your reply. Perhaps, open source things can popular more quickly than close source. Plus, MSVC isn't very faithful to the standard (Or, more frankly, has bugs).

MSVC is pretty much on par with Clang. Its Standard Library implementation has been consistently ahead of the competition. MSVC and Clang are substantially better than GCC in terms of compliance and completeness.
